# 'ng-if' - Multiple condition not working on template

Tags: angularjs, angular-directive

I have 3 variety of template. by `$index` conditionally i am applying the template.

here is my directive html :

```
<all-apps-gallery index="$index" app="app" update="update(app)" class="show" ng-repeat="app in allAppsBatch"></all-apps-gallery>
```

and  here is the directive:

```
var allAppsGallery = function ($compile, $animate) {

    return {

        restrict : 'E',

        replace : true,

        templateUrl : '/views/tools/gallery.html', // see below the html

        scope : {
            index : "=",
            update : "&",
            app : "="
        }

        }

    }

}

angular
    .module("tcpApp")
    .directive('allAppsGallery', allAppsGallery);
```

My `templateUrl''s html :

```
<div>

    <div ng-class="bgr box{{index}}" ng-click="update(app)" ng-if="{{index}} == 0 || {{index}} == 13 || {{index}} == 14 || {{index}} == 15 || {{index}} == 5 ">
    <h2>{{app.completion}} % {{index}}</h2>
        <span>{{app.name}}</span>
    </div>
    <div ng-class="bbr box{{index}}" ng-click="update(app)" ng-if="{{index}} == 2 || {{index}} == 3 || {{index}} == 4 || {{index}} == 6 || {{index}} == 10 || {{index}} == 11 || {{index}} == 12">
        <h2>{{app.completion}} %</h2>
        <span>{{app.name}}</span>
    </div>
    <div ng-class="bbl box{{index}}" ng-click="update(app)" ng-if="{{index}} == 1 || {{index}} == 7 || {{index}} == 8 || {{index}} == 9 ">
        <h2>{{app.completion}} %</h2>
        <span>{{app.name}}</span>
    </div>

</div>
```

Here according to the index value, i am switching the template. but it's not working for me. what is the wrong i made here?

Any one figure-out me please?

Thanks in advance.

I am getting this error:

[Error Link](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$parse/syntax?p0=%7B&p1=invalid%20key&p2=2&p3=%7B%7Bindex%7D%7D%20%3D%3D%200%20%7C%7C%20%7B%7Bindex%7D%7D%20%3D%3D%2013%20%7C%7C%20%7B%7Bindex%7D%7D%20%3D%3D%2014%20%7C%7C%20%7B%7Bindex%7D%7D%20%3D%3D%2015%20%7C%7C%20%7B%7Bindex%7D%7D%20%3D%3D%205&p4=%7Bindex%7D%7D%20%3D%3D%200%20%7C%7C%20%7B%7Bindex%7D%7D%20%3D%3D%2013%20%7C%7C%20%7B%7Bindex%7D%7D%20%3D%3D%2014%20%7C%7C%20%7B%7Bindex%7D%7D%20%3D%3D%2015%20%7C%7C%20%7B%7Bindex%7D%7D%20%3D%3D%205)

Comment: You shouldn't need the {{ }} in the ng-if statement.

Answer (score 1):

ngIf directive expects an expression, and hence you don't need to have interpolation tags {{ }} in it. Attribute value will be parsed and evaluated by Angular, however `{{` tags make value an invalid JS expression and cannot be processed.

Correct code would be

```
ng-if="index == 0 || index == 13 || index == 14 || index == 15 || index == 5 "
```

Comment: for adding class name as well?

Comment: No, ngClass is fine in this case, it can perfectly digest both expression and interpolation syntax.

Comment: But i am getting this error `http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.1/$parse/syntax?p0=box0&p1=is%20an%20unexpected%20token&p2=5&p3=bgr%20box0&p4=box0`

Comment: Ops, sorry, of course, ngClass should not have {{ in this case too.

Comment: do you mean like this: 'ng-class="bgr boxindex" '

Comment: In you want to use variable with ngClass you have several option: `ng-class="['bgr', 'box' + index]"` - array notation; `class="bgr box{{index}}"` - class attribute.

Comment: Is there a way to `unwrap` my template parent `div`

Comment: What do you mean "unwrap"?